# Use variable in wordpress function name

Tags: wordpress, function, variables

I am trying to create a function within a loop and the name of the function needs to change for each time it is executed.

Here is the function that works:

```
add_filter("gform_field_value_eventname", 'populate_event');
        function populate_event($value){
        return $eventtitle;
```

but I need it to do something like this, where a variable could be added to the name of the function:

```
add_filter("gform_field_value_eventname", 'populate_event'.$y);
        function populate_event.$y($value){
        return $eventtitle;
```

Please could somebody point me in the right direction

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead (`PHP 5 >= 5.3.0`):

```
add_filter("gform_field_value_eventname", function($value){
    // code...
});
```

Make decisions internally, maybe depending on the `$value`.

**Note:** if it doesn't solve your problem please post more relevant code.